# How do I split a DIV at a specific point using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, split, height

I an writing some JQuery to split some html code at a specific height. 
The html is user generated, and may contain images, so I can't think of a good way to do this server side.

I have some generated HTML like this:

```
<div id="1"> 
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Some More Text</p>
  <p>Even More Text</p>
  <p>Enough Text</p>
  <p>Too Much Text</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
```

I want the HTML to finally look like this:
(Splitting the content before it reaches 60 pixels high)

```
<div id="1"> 
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Some More Text</p>
  <p>Even More Text</p>
  <p>Enough Text</p>
</div>
<div id="split">
  <p>Too Much Text</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
```

I've written this JQuery:  I think I need to use .after maybe, or somehow refer back to the container div and close that.   $(this).parent or $(this).closest() ?

```
var h = 60;
/*Run when (item) is bigger than height.
Check and sum height of each base element, break up into 'h' px high divs*/

function pagebreak(item, h) {
    var st = 0; //st = space total
    $(item).children().each(function(i, l) {
        if (st + $(this).height() <= h) {
            st = st + $(this).height();
        } else {
            $(this).append('</div><div id="split">');
            st = 0;
        }
    });
}

$('div').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).first().height();
    if (len >= h) {
        pagebreak($(this), h);
    }
});
```

But it's giving back HTML like so:

```
<div id="1">
    <p>Some Text</p>   
    <p>Some More Text</p>   
    <p>Even More Text</p>   
    <p>Enough Text<div id="split"></div></p>   
    <p>Too Much Text</p> 
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
```

Any help very much appreciated.
What I really want to say in my function is    split item at $this with a new div.
Thanks in advance.
First question on StackOverflow, so sorry if I've done anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your `pagebreak` function to return a set of the elements that occur after the split point. Call it `GetElementsAfterSplit()`.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).first().height();
    if (len >= h) {
        var splitElements = GetElementsAfterSplit();

        // move elements from old location to new
        splitElements.remove();
        $(this).after($("<div class=\"split\"></div>").append(splitElements));
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I add the elements that occur after the split to an array?

Comment: Start a jquery set using the empty `var set = $()` function. Then use the [JQuery add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function to add each item.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem.
Anno 2014 i came up with this solution

```
    var h = 60;
    var c = 0;
    $('#1').children().each(function () {
        c += $(this).height();
        if (h < c) {
            $(this).appendTo('#2');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even Your requirement is slightly different but [this](http://easystreaming.blogspot.com/2010/04/truncate-by-height.html) may help you. Download the zip file and open html file in browser and click on button. it will automatically divide the html content.