# Split div into divs with max height per div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, split

Trying to figure out a way to split a div into separate divs om the height 500 px. Code below so far. Any hints?

```
<div id="test"> LOTS of TEXT WITH HEIGHT OVER 500PX</div>
```

Jquery

```
if($("#test").height()>500){
    //Split div into divs of 500 pix

}
```

**Edit:**
the div area is fixed width. I am using it in a page break function and need to handle the situation where a div is longer than a page and needs to split into several smaller divs to be able to work in the pagebreak function

Comment: You could remove the `<div>` and append new elements. $( ".container" ).append( "<div></div> ..." );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a DIV at a specific point using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135522/how-do-i-split-a-div-at-a-specific-point-using-jquery)

Comment: Well I don't have any children within the div, only raw text. How can I identify specific points without an element as in the example above?

Comment: @KevinLindmark what if one starts resizing the window? (And I have minimally a couple of other questions/possible-issues - just because your question is too vague. Why are you doing what you do and what's the end result?)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the div area is fixed width. I am using it in a page break function and need to handle the situation where a div is longer than a page and needs to split into several smaller divs to be able to work in the pagebreak function.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's super-performant, but one way to do it (or hopefully to give you an idea) would be:

- Iterate the element's ***TextNode*** characters
- At each character calculate the `Range`'s *y* `boundingClientRect().bottom`
- Populate your `pages` array at the **index** number derived from *`floor(y / breakAtY)`*
- **Return an Array** containing the *pagination breakpoints* texts

<sub>Example using `100`px as page break:</sub>

```js
function paginate(el, breakAtY) {
  const pages = [],
    elY = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    node = el.childNodes[0], // TextNode
    text = el.textContent,
    len = text.length,
    rng = document.createRange();

  for (var c = 0; c < len; c++) {
    rng.setStart(node, c);
    const i = ~~((rng.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - elY) / breakAtY);
    pages[i] = (pages[i] || '') + text[c];
  }
  return pages;
}


const myPages = paginate(document.getElementById("demo"), 100);
console.log(myPages); // Array of three pages text
```

```css
#demo { font-size: 1.2em; width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div id="demo">Example using 100px height pagination - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque consequatur rerum, quia placeat praesentium, sapiente eos qui omnis ratione repellendus accusamus, voluptates quos corrupti recusandae officiis quam rem, sint at. Iusto omnis, quas facere neque delectus aliquam, eligendi quibusdam ea. Inventore vitae aspernatur nihil est obcaecati rerum cupiditate sequi nemo temporibus fugiat.</div>
```

**NOTICE**: as per requirement, the above is meant to be used on Elements having exclusively TextNode as its only childNode (No inner elements!)

Answer (score 0):

Use `page-break-after` to manually set page breaks for printing purposes.

To visually display "page breaks", CSS can do this without altering the text content. JavaScript is used to calculate the number of "page breaks" needed based on the height of the text. The example below uses a page break distance of 100px to keep the example compact, but it can easily be changed to 500px for longer text.

I'll leave it to wiser folks to delve into the black arts behind pseudo elements and explain why this even works. All I understand is somehow the `:before` on the wrapper combined with `clear:both` on the page break element allows the text to flow into the gaps that it couldn't otherwise.

Edit: fixed for better visualization, testing, naming. Now correctly accounts for distance + height, including offset for first child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let text = $('#test'),
    pb_distance = 100,
    pages = Math.floor(text.height() / pb_distance);

  for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    text.prepend("<div class='pb_wrapper'><div class='pagebreak'></div></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 20px; /* testing to confirm 5 lines per page */
}

.pagebreak {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 19px 0 20px 0; /* pagebreak effective height */
}

.pb_wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 140px; /* pb_distance + pagebreak effective height */
}

.pb_wrapper:first-child:before {
  height: 100px; /* pb_distance */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt vulputate malesuada. Nulla rhoncus ornare lectus, eget tristique ex euismod nec. Cras tempor quam a sem ullamcorper pharetra. Vivamus pretium lectus lobortis aliquam pretium. Ut tincidunt
  leo nisl, sed hendrerit metus placerat ut. Vivamus tincidunt mollis laoreet. Sed ullamcorper, nisi vel feugiat accumsan, lacus massa placerat enim, sit amet finibus odio sem at diam. Proin eleifend semper finibus. Sed ac bibendum felis. In imperdiet
  ipsum a magna molestie, non sollicitudin lorem lobortis. Fusce porta laoreet erat, et varius ipsum egestas sed. Pellentesque ornare tellus a nibh mollis, at rhoncus purus suscipit. Sed tempor eget sem at molestie. Etiam egestas porttitor lorem quis
  scelerisque. Nullam nibh dolor, imperdiet et felis ut, tempus pellentesque quam.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt vulputate malesuada. Nulla rhoncus ornare lectus, eget tristique ex euismod nec. Cras tempor quam a sem ullamcorper pharetra. Vivamus pretium lectus lobortis aliquam pretium. Ut tincidunt
  leo nisl, sed hendrerit metus placerat ut. Vivamus tincidunt mollis laoreet. Sed ullamcorper, nisi vel feugiat accumsan, lacus massa placerat enim, sit amet finibus odio sem at diam. Proin eleifend semper finibus. Sed ac bibendum felis. In imperdiet
  ipsum a magna molestie, non sollicitudin lorem lobortis. Fusce porta laoreet erat, et varius ipsum egestas sed. Pellentesque ornare tellus a nibh mollis, at rhoncus purus suscipit. Sed tempor eget sem at molestie. Etiam egestas porttitor lorem quis
  scelerisque. Nullam nibh dolor, imperdiet et felis ut, tempus pellentesque quam.
</div>
```